# Error: Could not find or load main class scala.tools.nsc.Main

Tags: scala, command-line

So I have just started working with Scala. After playing around with the REPL I tried to compile my first program. I tried just running the HelloWorld program from the Scala website:

```
//Scala
object HelloWorld {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("Hello, world!")
   }
}
```

When I tried compiling this code (saved as test.scala) with

```
...user$scalac test.scala
```

I got a strange error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class scala.tools.nsc.Main
```

I would like to find out A) What does this error mean, and B) What can I do to fix this problem?

Thanks for any Help

Answer (score 0):

It's seems something wrong with your environment. Scalac is script that run Main class from scala-compiler.jar (usually is located in $SCALA_HOME\lib). So check environment variable, lib folder and scalac script if you modified it.

Answer (score 0):

if in windows, make sure the install directory not contains space symbol. typically 
 do not install scala into 'Program Files' , 'Program Files(x86)'.